# Chaining Observables resulting in nested observables

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm new to RxJS and Observables so I'm still trying to wrap my head around the right way to do things.

I have two functions:

```
functionRetrieveStuff() : Observable<MyObject> {}

functionDoStuff(param1: MyObject) : Observable<boolean> {}
```

The output of RetrieveStuff is the input for DoStuff.  I call these from instead the following:

```
mainFunction() : Observable<boolean> {
    return this.functionRetrieveStuff().map(response => {
        return this.functionDoStuff(response);
    })
}
```

This results in the following compile error:

```
Error:(33, 16) TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
```

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

If I'm reading the documentation at reactivex.io correctly, I think the solution to my problems is switchMap.  So if I update my mainFunction to this:

```
mainFunction() : Observable<boolean> {
    return functionRetrieveStuff().switchMap(response => {
        return functionDoStuff(response);
    })
}
```

The compiling error goes away, but I get an error when I use the mainFunction in my canActivate guard when I try use the function:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchMap' of undefined
```

Here's how I use mainFunction in my canActivate guard's canActivate method:

```
return this.mainFunction().first().map(result => {
        return true;
    });
```

So I'm not sure if I'm using mainFunction is incorrect or if I'm calling it incorrectly.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any call to mainFunction in your guard. It seems you also forgot to use `this` when calling functionDoStuff. Post your real, actual code that reproduces the error. Not some other vaguely resembling code.

Comment: and `functionRetrieveStuff` code

Comment: Sorry about that, I can't post the full code so I was trying to simplify it down to what was needed to illustrate what I'm doing.  I've update my code.

Comment: So functionRetrieveStuff() returns undefined.

Comment: In an earlier version of mainFunction, I did subscribe to functionRetrieveStuff() and I would get data back.  But I needed to update mainFunction to return an Observable<boolean> instead of just a boolean.   So in my update of mainFunction, it seems like something to observe functionRetrieveStuff got lost.

Comment: And I just found the missing return in one of an else case inside the logic of functionRetrieveStuff.  Fixed the return and applied switchmap inside that method where it was needed and all is happy now.

JB Nizet, your comment pushed me in the right direction, but I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer.  Any way I can give you karma for helping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `switchMap`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

And then use it like you are in this:

```
mainFunction() : Observable<boolean> {
    return this.functionRetrieveStuff().switchMap(response => this.functionDoStuff(response));
}
```

Since the router can automatically subscribe to observables, you will want your canActivate function to look like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.mainFunction().first();  //this return Observable<boolean> since functionDoStuff is Observable<boolean>
}
```

Comment: when the canActivate guard returns the observable to the router, the router subscribes to it, doesn't it?

Comment: You are correct.  Guards can return observables that the router subscribes to.  I'll update my answer.